# How to make google approve my app with MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-developers-console

I request this permission (MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE?) because I need to upload pdf and xml files from my device to my app. I need that to be able to load them in android 11 api > 29. Is there any solution to get my app approved by google?

[Google rejection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtmS8.png)

Comment: Hi there, do your app need to manage the external storage?

Comment: You have to use storage access framework to access those files, google is very adamant about denying this permission unless you're writing a file manager app.

Comment: But if I want to upload a PDF file in android 11 the only way that I can do that is using MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: `But if I want to upload a PDF file in android 11 the only way that I can do that is using MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` No. Nonsense. We do it all without. You can do too.

Comment: "But if I want to upload a PDF file in android 11 the only way that I can do that is using MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" -- why do you think this?

Comment: Please refer to this link: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files